# UI Testing tvOS Textfields

Tags: swift, uitextfield, swift2, tvos, apple-tv

I'm trying to implement UI testing for a tvOS application and I've ran into a bit of a problem.

During ***Record UI Test***, when I enter a textfield and begin typing (on the keyboard), reasonably it creates the code:

```
myTextField.typeText("String")
```

But, every time the test is run, it will crash at that line with the error:

`Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Failed to receive event delivery confirmation within 20.0s of the original dispatch.`

For reference I've attached the code in context below:

```
let myTextField = XCUIApplication().textFields["myTextField"]
XCTAssert(myTextField.hasFocus)
XCUIRemote.sharedRemote().pressButton(.Select)
myTextField.typeText("String") <-- Crashes here
XCUIRemote.sharedRemote().pressButton(.Select)
```

I realize it might be because users would not have access to a keyboard on the actual device (unless they have the updated Remote app).

**Is there an easier way to simulate entering text into a textfield in tvOS?**

I would prefer not having to create a ton of `XCUIRemote.sharedRemote().pressButton(.Direction)` over and over again.

Comment: Man I wish this question had an answer. UI Testing on tvOS is the absolute worst. Even in the latest version of Xcode, 8.2.1, it still records tests with .tap() even though none of those are recognized in tvOS. If you haven't already, file radars against this stuff so they know we want to have good tests.